# What is wrong with continuing to publish with my PhD adviser?

Tags: industry, independent-researcher

I have heard that it is 'bad' to continue to publish with your adviser after you get your PhD. Or is this something that is debated in the academic community?

In my situation, after my PhD, I can get a job in industry, but I am allowed time (half a day a week) to continue my research at my local university. This allows me to continue researching something that I am interested in, rather than researching something that someone else is interested in.

I can understand that every publication should not be between myself and my adviser. And I can understand that I should show that I am an independent researcher. But does that mean I should stop publishing with my (ex-)adviser?

Comment: By continuing to publish with your advisor, your advisor may be demonstrating a lack of independence. Encourage her to publish some papers on her own.

Comment: What industry are you working on if you don't mind me asking. The allowed time for independent research sounds very appealing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By continuing to publish with your advisor, you are not showing that you are an independent researcher. People will always question whether it is possibly your advisor that is doing the work, coming up with the ideas, guiding the research plan, and simply by looking at your publication record, there is no evidence that this is not the case.

If on the other hand, you publish papers alone or with different coauthors, and you have a clear research plan, independent of your advisors, then you will start to demonstrate your independence.

But it is okay to continue publishing with your advisor – I still do – as long as your record says **I am independent**.

Answer (score 27):

There's nothing “wrong” with continuing to publish with your (ex-)adviser. You have correctly identified the issue to avoid: **after getting your PhD, the next step in your career is to establish yourself as an independent researcher.** Thus, of course: *depending on the context,* publishing with your adviser might send the wrong signal!

So, you should continue to publish with her, but you should make sure that it's not 100% of your research (and publications). Another point that makes a big difference is if you can, maybe now or maybe after some time, take the lead in that collaboration.